# For loop (nested) for value_counts() with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a `DataFrame` like the following one:

[image]

Now I would like to do `value_counts()`, but the problem I have is when I use the following code:

```
with open('out.csv', 'w') as out:
    for col in df.columns:
        res = df[col].value_counts()\
                     .reset_index()\
                     .rename(columns={col: 'count', 'index': col})\

        res.to_csv(out, index=False)
```

I get the following wrong results:

[image]

But what I need is the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) + [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html)

You can apply `value_counts` to each series, then melt your dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'01-01-2018': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2],
                   '02-01-2018': [4, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1]})

res = df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).reset_index()
res = pd.melt(res, id_vars='index')
res.columns = ['Code', 'Date', 'Freq']

print(res)

   Code        Date  Freq
0     1  01-01-2018     2
1     2  01-01-2018     2
2     3  01-01-2018     1
3     4  01-01-2018     1
4     1  02-01-2018     2
5     2  02-01-2018     1
6     3  02-01-2018     2
7     4  02-01-2018     1
```